# SQL Server 2005 Delete Query SLOW

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Delete Query that each day needs to run deleting any data that is greater than 7 days old which is about 6 Million Records.

My table should only store data for the last 7 days.

Here is the query I am running:

```
DELETE FROM [tblTSS_DataCollection]
Where [DatapointDate] < DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE())
```

This query takes 5.5 minutes to execute. I have an index setup that includes this so I don't think it should be taking this long to execute:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblTSS_DataCollection] ON [dbo].  [tblTSS_DataCollection] 
(
[DataPointID] ASC,
[DatapointDate] ASC,
[AssetID] ASC
)
```

Is there a better way to delete this data? It takes forever and I really need to be able to delete this data quickly.

Comment: The fact that you have index set up is slowing it down, because it also has to delete from index. Also if you have FK relations make sure they are not cascading. Try deleting in smaller chunks, like 1000 records at a time.

Comment: I have to have the index because I also query this data as well to show in charts

Comment: I understand that. Not saying to remove it, but it sure doesn't help in DELETE

Comment: Yes I understand that now I just need to understand how to speed up the delete

Comment: You can't actually speed it up, but you can make it less noticeable by breaking into smaller batches in a while loop and executing the loop until @@rowcount=0. That way your table is not locked for too long and transaction log is not growing exponentially (See Aaron's post for code example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index doesn't really support the query since the query doesn't reference the leading key column. So, it has to scan the entire table with or without this index. You might consider an index on DataPointDate alone to support this delete operation if it's something you run often.

If DataPointID is an IDENTITY column, and DataPointDate is entered sequentially, you might also consider this variation:

```
DECLARE @maxID INT;

SELECT @maxID = MAX(DataPointID) 
  FROM dbo.tblTSS_DataCollection
  WHERE [DatapointDate] < DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE());

DELETE dbo.tblTSS_DataCollection
  WHERE DataPointID <= @maxID;
```

Another thing you might consider doing (if it's the delete and not the scan contributing to the slowness) is (a) making sure your log has enough room to accommodate the delete, and isn't killing you with a bunch of autogrows, and (b) performing the work in batches:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT 1;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

  DELETE TOP (1000) dbo.tblTSS_DataCollection WHERE ...
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: I have to have the index because I also query this data as well to show in charts. So should I create a new index as well that includes this Column?

Comment: @kevinc I wasn't suggesting to get rid of the current index, so you can stop defending it. I'm just explaining to you that it doesn't help you with this specific delete query.

Comment: BEGIN TRANSACTION; WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN COMMIT TRANSACTION; DELETE TOP (1000) dbo.tblTSS_DataCollection WHERE [DatapointDate] < DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE()); END COMMIT TRANSACTION;

I ran this and this does not delete....

Comment: @kevinc sorry, needed to set @@ROWCOUNT somehow first. But please, don't post code in comments. Nobody can read that.

Comment: for 163,000 rows it took a little over a minute and half to execute is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @kevinc I can't think of much else, no. Run the delete more frequently?

Comment: Whenever I do a Select Count(*) where the datapointdate is 7 days old it takes 5 seconds to respond.... could this be a problem?

Comment: @kevinc well, again, if you're doing this often, you may consider an index on just the datapointdate column. You do understand why a delete takes a lot longer than a select count, right?

Comment: of course I understand, let me try creating an index now just on the DatapointDate

Comment: Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: I fixed it, I actually had to add two additional indexes as it slowed down a few other queries that are constantly pulling but overall fixed it with your second solution. Cheers mate